# Add border line to tab content bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add a border line to surround tab content here is what I'm working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/0trcdLb2/

```
<div class="col-xs-3"> <!-- required for floating -->
          <!-- Nav tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-right sideways">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home-vr" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile-vr" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#messages-vr" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings-vr" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

[image]

Desired output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap columns have padding to the left & right of `15px`.

You can add a class to your `div.col-xs-9` element that "overrides" that.

Here's an example for your right panel:

```
.tab-wrapper-right {
    margin-left: -15px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

And the HTML will look something like:

```
<div class="col-xs-9 tab-wrapper-right">
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home-v">Home Tab.</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile-v">Profile Tab.</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages-v">Messages Tab.</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="settings-v">Settings Tab.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0trcdLb2/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Just some changes, based on the aifrim's modifications to get exactly the wanted result:

[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/0trcdLb2/6/)

You should be set the height manually (ideally with javascript) if the content will be larger, like I do with :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
        tmp = $('.tab-content').height();
    $('#lastLi').css('height', (tmp-133)+'px');
});
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that there will be info there to outflow the panel. But good idea.